# creating objects from C# class to use them in database functions

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I have created class in C# i need to use objects from this class to add them to a databse table.

the information come from textbox go into the object of the class 
than from this object i want to preform databse function any help

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you are talking about POCOs (Plain Old CLR Objects) and some way to persist those within a database, I think what you are looking for is an ORM (Object Relational Mapper) or a NoSQL solution could also work. [Entity Framework 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28VS.80%29.aspx) may well fit your needs and is by Microsoft so well supported and lots has been and is being written about it. I'd recommend [Julie Lerman's book](http://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?ie=UTF8&location=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FProgramming-Entity-Framework-Julia-Lerman%2Fdp%2F059652028X&tag=thdafa-20&linkCode=ur2&camp=1789&creative=9325).

Comment: @Mohamed: Earlier versions of EF exist for 3.5 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree that it sounds like you'd want to use an ORM (Object Relational Mapper).  There are a slew out there - some are more geared towards direct table to object relations, etc.

Personally, I'd recommend NHibernate (or Fluent NHibernate).  It gets you out of the goo of having to do left had/right hand stored procedure setups, and once you make the investment in learning it, is definitely time well spent (we use it for all of our projects and have seen some great productivity increases).

I'm not 100% sold on EF4 - which, while better than EF1, is still a bit too green and IMO has not yet proven itself in the market, although time will tell.

FYI - I have a series of NHibernate tutorials up on my blog that will get you from zero to at least getting some basic stuff done (the link is in my profile).